# debootstrap --variant=buildd couln't find build-essential

Tags: debootstrap

I am preparing chroot

```
sudo debootstrap --verbose  --include=apt     --cache-dir=/var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/aptcache     --variant=buildd --no-check-gpg --components=main,contrib,non-free,arm64     4.7_arm     /home/user/PROSTOR/pkg-csp/builplace     https://dl.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/4.7_arm/repository-base
```

with following logs

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/ef950310535f0ee9f3fa76853aa635b0/raw/b8b61dd16037a14ad5996e7f853727a0408e52f7/sudo%2520debootstrap%2520--verbose

debootstrap.log:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/4881c9a15bb43c399e12c3a616e4cc6a/raw/957072a03913cd3ffd953da227cbfb52665b5c40/debootstrap.log

I  know for sure where build-essential is

```
sudo apt show build-essential
Package: build-essential
Version: 12.6
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 20.5 kB
Depends: libc6-dev | libc-dev, gcc (>= 4:8.3), g++ (>= 4:8.3), make, dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11)
Download-Size: 7,588 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://dl.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/4.7_arm/repository-base 4.7_arm/main arm64 Packages
```

But still can not create chroot. Could you help me to do that?

**UPD**

```
sudo apt show linux-libc-dev-5.10.0-1057
Package: linux-libc-dev-5.10.0-1057
Version: 5.10.0-1057.astra6+ci79
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Source: linux-5.10
Maintainer: JSC RPA RusBITech <support@rusbitech.ru>
Installed-Size: 6,298 kB
Provides: aufs-dev, linux-kernel-headers, linux-libc-dev
Conflicts: linux-kernel-headers
Replaces: linux-kernel-headers
Download-Size: 1,535 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://dl.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/4.7_arm/repository-base 4.7_arm/main arm64 Packages



sudo debootstrap --verbose  --include=apt     --cache-dir=/var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/aptcache     --variant=buildd --no-check-gpg --components=arm64     4.7_arm/main     /home/user/PROSTOR/pkg-csp/builplace     https://dl.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/4.7_arm/repository-main
E: No such script: /usr/share/debootstrap/scripts/4.7_arm/main
```

Comment: The problem isn’t that `build-essential` isn’t found, it is; the problem is that `linux-libc-dev` isn’t installed, which means `libc6-dev` can’t be configured, which means that `libstdc++-dev` can’t be configured, which means `g++-8` can’t be configured, which means `build-essential` can’t be configured.

Comment: @StephenKitt linux-libc-dev is already installed on HOST SYSTEM, what do you mean "installed"?

Comment: `debootstrap` doesn’t care about the host system, it cares about the chroot. Search for `linux-libc-dev` in `debootstrap.log`.

Comment: @StephenKitt "Package linux-libc-dev is not installed." so? how to fix that?

Comment: If I knew that, I would have written an answer.