# How to install packages into chroot?

Tags: debian, chroot, debootstrap

This question is related to [debootstrap --variant=buildd couln't find build-essential](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726675/debootstrap-variant-buildd-coulnt-find-build-essential)

As I know debootstrap may run the script after or before creating chroot

```
debootstrap [OPTION...] SUITE TARGET [MIRROR [SCRIPT]]
```

Ppl told me that I can place packages installation into this script to install required packages. Please tell me how to do that, to fix the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--include` option. For example, an i386 `chroot` I made recently.

```
sudo debootstrap --include=nano,gcc,clang,tcc,pcc,g++,git,make,bash,python2,python3,libgsl-dev,libboost-dev,libopenlibm-dev --arch=i386 stable debian_11_i386
```

A few times I've needed to run `apt --fix-broken install` inside the `chroot` after `debootstrap` finished.